# Database Mirroring login attempt failed with error: 'Connection handshake failed. An OS call failed:(8009030c) 0x8009030c(The logon attempt failed)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, mirroring

In SQL server 2016 instance, Database Mirroring went to disconnected state due to below error. The below error logged in sql server error log.

**Database Mirroring login attempt failed with error: 'Connection handshake failed. An OS call failed:(8009030c) 0x8009030c(The logon attempt failed). State 67**

After sometime all DB's went to synchronized state automatically. Four days before we have performed password reset for SQL service account and updated the new password for SQL services.

why this is happening?

Comment: You'll want to check the security log in windows for why the logon attempt failed. SQL is telling you the OS gave back an error, this is outside of SQL.

Comment: This message got logged in event viewer at the time of mirror disconnect. 
 **The Network Setup Service service entered the stopped state. The Network Setup Service service entered the running state. Event ID 7036**

Comment: That's not the problem, unless you were in the middle of installing a network driver.